# Display JSON Data in HTML using Laravel 4

Tags: php, ajax, json, laravel-4

Please help me with my problem in displaying JSON data into my view..

my script is:

```
 $('#supplierId').change(function(){
 $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", 
    { option: $(this).val() }, 
    function(data) {
      var firstnameID = $('#firstnameID');
      $.each(data, function(index, element) {   
          firstnameID.val(element.first_name);
     });
  });
});
```

and my JSON reply is:

```
{"id":7,"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe"}
```

the thing is when i tried to:

```
alert(element.first_name);
```

it says UNDEFINED, but when I:

```
alert(element);
```

it gives me the value of the last name which is Doe.. my question is how can I then access the other values like the ID and the first name..

EDITED:

this is my route:

```
Route::get('api/dropdown', function(){
$input = Input::get('option');
$supllier = Supplier::find($input);
returnResponse::json($supllier->select(array('id','first_name','last_name'))
    ->find($input));
});
```

Please help me with this one, This is my first time using JSON so im a bit confuse on how this works.

Best Regards 
-Melvn

Comment: the problem is in your js, what are your trying to do ?

Comment: rather than use `alert()`, try displaying it in the browser's console using `console.log()` ... the console handles these js objects much better than alert

Comment: Hello @VitKos i want to auto fill some text box with other user details like last_name, adress, etc automatically once i select a specific id on my select box..

Comment: In terms of future usage.. you might want to consider using `URL::route()` or `URL::action()` to reference your AJAX script.  I have created an `AjaxController` for this in the past..

Comment: Browsers have consoles, use them to see the result of your request. If an error had occurred in your code the response may not be JSON at all, if you dont handle these exceptions with `App::error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using each? This should work:

```
$('#supplierId').change(function(){
 $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", 
    { option: $(this).val() }, 
    function(data) {
      var firstnameID = $('#firstnameID');

          firstnameID.val(data.first_name);

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that answer.. Im not really good on javascript and ajax.. i just did copied it on another site.. but this one really did the job! Im very glad right now Thank YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, give this a try..

Explicitly state that what you're expecting back from the server is JSON using the [`dataType` option in `get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$('#supplierId').change(function()
{
  $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", 
    { option: $(this).val() }, 
    function(data) 
    {
      var firstnameID = $('#firstnameID');
      $.each(data, function(index, element) 
      {   
        firstnameID.val(element.first_name);
      });
    },
    'json' // <<< this is the dataType
  );
});
```

Now you should be able to access the data using the dot syntax:

```
console.log("last_name: " + element.last_name);
console.log("first_name: " + element.first_name);
console.log("id: " + element.id);
```

I would add another few lines, just to check that you're getting back what you expect to see:

```
console.log("NEW ELEMENT"); // << indicator in the console for your reference
console.log(element); // << the whole "element"
```

Comment: Thanks for that code @msturdy, but im still getting the same error.. CONSOLE LOG IS: 
last_name: undefined 7:421
first_name: undefined 7:422
id: undefined 7:423
NEW ELEMENT 7:424
7 7:425
last_name: undefined 7:421
first_name: undefined 7:422
id: undefined 7:423
NEW ELEMENT 7:424
John 7:425
last_name: undefined 7:421
first_name: undefined 7:422
id: undefined 7:423
NEW ELEMENT 7:424
Doe

Comment: ok, put a `console.log(data)` in at the beginning of the function() to check what you're getting back from the server...

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me out with this one.. I really appreciated it and I learned also something new from you.. The error on my part was Im using each method..!

Comment: by the way.. Object {id: 7, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe"} was the product of console.log(data);

Comment: aaah, then I was mistaken in my understanding.. I thought you would have more than one person in the JSON, and therefore looping through them! In which case the `each()` would be quite appropriate! :)  glad you solved it!